# OnMouseDown not work in Vuforia - Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia, onmousedown

I'm testing AR in Unity with Vuforia and I can't have the event `OnMouseDown()` working correctly.

It happens that the first time I hit play it works but just one time.
I've already checked that the collider is activated and well positioned.
Also I see that the check of the script in the GameObject (Cube in this case) is not enabled, it doesn't even appear like the rest of the scripts when components are made.

This is the code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Click : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        Debug.Log("CLICK!!!");
    }
}
```

[image: When is in play]

[image: When is in scene]

[image: In the project]

I don't have any error messages or warnings in the console.

This is the repository, branch `develop`:
https://github.com/emicalvacho/MapaMentalAR.git

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't just have a collider and use `OnMouseDown`. Pretty sure that is made for UI Selectable/Interactable elements. You'll need to use raycast to see if user has clicked the 3D object. Check out: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenPointToRay.html

Comment: @user14492 their documentation disagrees with you: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html  "OnMouseDown is called when the user has pressed the mouse button while over the GUIElement or Collider."

Comment: But OnMouseDown will only work if the script is enabled, if it is disabled that is possibly your issue.

Comment: Maybe you can upload a screenshot of your GameObject on the inspector before and after you click on it.

Comment: @Eddge afaik you additionally need either UI or a renderer. Not rendered objects might not be clickable .. but not sure on this one since the Docs are not that clear on that

Comment: `Also I see that the check of the script in the GameObject (Cube in this case) is not enabled, it doesn't even appear like the rest of the scripts when components are made.` sounds like the object is disabled .. if that's the case obviously the script won't be running since also the Collider will be disabled

Comment: @derHugo Not sure either on the renderer part, I will check that in a bit.

Comment: @Eddge nah, just did and it actually also works with disabled renderer. Empty GameObject with a collider should be enough

Comment: So What is the solutions according to you?

Comment: @Calvin ... is the GameObject this script is attached to enabled in the hierarchy? Is the collider enabled? Is this component enabled?

Comment: @Calvin I don't know how exactly you are using this ... I cloned your project ... I guess you are talking about the `Object` prefab ... which works just fine for me when just placed somewhere into the scene ...

Comment: @derHugo the objects are not in the hierarchy because these are generate when the user clicks the AddButton. Yes, the collider is enabled, I upload the images. Also, the componente is enabled.

Comment: Yes I saw that .. however it was spawned far out of field of view .. but after I moved it so I can see it through the camera I could click it just fine ... Is it possible something in front of it is blocking the click / catching the click before you do

Comment: @derHugo yes, the Object prefab is placed well, but when I clicked the object, this does not activate the event

Comment: @derHugo You were generated out of the field of vision because you do not have the image in the database of vuforia, if you want I can upload it to the git for you to try.

Comment: @Calvin I can't print it out anyways ... is there also a reason why use a ScreenSpace-Camera not a screenSpace-Overlay canvas?

Comment: @derHugo I don't think it worked with Overlay, but I can try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out: You are always hovering the `Hola` text on the object .. not the cube. It blocks the raycast!

How I found out: I wrote a simple script for finding out what is currently hovered:

```
public class RayDebugger : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void OnGUI()
    {
        GUI.color = Color.green;

        var hovering = EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject();

        var isHovering = hovering ? "Yes" : "No";

        GUI.Label(new Rect(100, 100, 200, 200), $"Is hovering something? - {isHovering}");

        if (!hovering) return;

        var pointer = new PointerEventData(EventSystem.current) { position = Input.mousePosition };

        var raycastResults = new List<RaycastResult>();
        EventSystem.current.RaycastAll(pointer, raycastResults);

        if (raycastResults.Count > 0)
        {
            GUI.Label(new Rect(100, 200, 200, 200), $"Currently Hovered: {raycastResults[0]}");
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see it is always your "Hola" `Text` component:

[image]

(and yes I just used a "dynamic image" target :D )

---

You can fix this in a few steps:

1. Disable `RaycastTarget` on the `Text` component:

   [image]

   this way it doesn't interfere with the pointer raycast
2. For getting a 3D collider your `Camera` should have a `PhysicsRaycaster` component attached:

   [image]
3. I don't know why exactly but it only works if you use a **Perspective** `Camera`. Vuforia somehow seems to have a trouble with an *Orthographic* one .. understandable because for such a camera no distances exist. So rather switch you camera to `Perspective`

   [image]

---

Now I can add and click on the cubes:

[image]

---

Btw

> I don't think it worked with Overlay, but I can try.

as the info box says without a `Camera` referenced (which is the case in your scene) a `ScreenSpace - Camera` just behaves equal to a `ScreenSpace - Overlay`.

Comment: I know I shouldn't thank you in the comments, but it's impossible not to recognize that you've taken your time to help me and that's acknowledged. Thank you very much!
And that RayDebugger is a trick that I will take into account for my next projects.